# How to generate core dump for a child thread in Android

Tags: android, linux, multithreading, webkit, coredump

When I visited a website by Android browser, the browser was blocked. The browser process had two threads, one was a main UI thread(tid 2050), the other was a working thread (tid 2060) which was created by the UI thread. I found the UI thread was OK, but the child thread was blocked.

I can get the java stack information of the child thread by:
kill -3 2050

/data/anr/traces.txt

```
...
"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x43d54e58 self=0x236408
  | sysTid=2060 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=2319688
  at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeAddData(Native Method)
  at android.webkit.LoadListener.commitLoad(LoadListener.java:1219)
  at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:208)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Can I also get the native core dump of the child thread (2060)?

BTW, when I tried:
kill -11 2050
I can get native core dump of the main thread(2050) in adb log.
but the command did not work for the child thread.

I would be very thankful for any advice or ideas.